# Unable to set zoomControlOptions on Google Maps in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3, angular2-google-maps

First, I get the native Google maps element, because as far as I can tell, the Angular 2 API doesn't expose it. That looks like the code below and works fine:

```
import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

constructor(public mapApiWrapper: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper ) {}

this.mapApiWrapper.getNativeMap().then((map)=> {}
```

All this works great and I am able to set options on the native map element, for example, the code below works:

```
    let position: any = new google.maps.LatLng(45.521, -122.677);

    map.setOptions({
      zoom: 1,
      center: position
    });
```

However, when I try to set [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) and move the zoom controls via [ZoomControlOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ZoomControlOptions), I get a bunch of errors. What I try is this:

```
    let zoomControlOptions: any = new google.maps.zoomControlOptions({
      style: google.maps.ControlPosition.small,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
    });
```

This throws:

> TypeError: google.maps.zoomControlOptions is not a constructor

If I try to do this:

```
    map.setOptions({
      zoom: 1,
      center: position,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ControlPosition.small,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
      }
    });
```

it throws:

> Argument of type '{ zoom: number; center: any; zoomControlOptions: {
>   style: any; position: any; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'MapOptions'.   Object literal may only specify known properties,
>   and 'zoomControlOptions' does not exist in type 'MapOptions'

I am pretty lost at this point, because I see that `MapOptions` takes a `zoomControlOptions` arg in the docs...

Answer (score 1):

As you are manipulating directly the native map, you are outside angular2-google-maps universe.

### EDIT

Previous answer for #1 was wrong, it seems there is no such thing than a ZoomControlOptions constructor. Creating an object litteral works fine.

```
let zoomControlOptions: any = new {
  style: google.maps.ControlPosition.small,
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
);
```

As for issue #2, examples around ([here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trymap_controls_modify1) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning)) always set zoomControlOptions along with zoomControl: true

Comment: Hmm, I still get "TypeError: google.maps.ZoomControlOptions is not a constructor"